# Why is SomeObject that inherits SubClass<T> not of type SubClass<object>?

Tags: c#, generics

```
SomeObject is SubClass<foo>
```

Evaluates as `true` but this:

```
SomeObject is SubClass<object>
```

Is `false`

Why? `foo` is a class, therefore isn't it an object?

Comment: This is not a mater of inheritance. But of co- and contravariance. It looks similar to inheritance and casting because it is  designed to look similar. But it is not similar. `SubClass<foo>`is not `SubClass<object>` anymore then it is `SubClass<bar>`

Comment: Ah that makes some sense. Is there a way to check if an object is SubClass<T> where T is any type?

Comment: Use an interface

Comment: Not easiliy I don't think. What are you trying to do? There might be simpler ways

Comment: Read Eric Lippert's and Jon Skeet's answers in both duplicates. Both should answer your question.